# how to print a string in method which type is integer in setter?

Tags: c#

This my class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Car
    {
        private string brand;
        private string color;
        private int model;

        public Car(string Brand, string Color, int aModel)
        {
            brand = Brand;
            color = Color;
            Model = aModel;
        }

        public void carGet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(brand);
            Console.WriteLine(color);
            Console.WriteLine(model);
        }

        public int Model
        {
            get { return model; }
            set
            {
                if (value < 2019)
                    Console.WriteLine("old");
                else
                    model = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is main

```
using ConsoleApp1;
using System;

namespace consoleapp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car car = new Car("ford","Red",2001);
            
            car.carGet();
        }
    }
}
```

I need to print to print a string  "old" if the model was earlier than 2019 but suddenly I got this output :

```
old
ford
Red
0
```

instead of :

```
ford
Red
old
```

How to solve that to make it work normally or (as I need)?

Comment: You need to remove `if(value < 2019).....` block from `set` of `Model`. You should just have `model=value` in `set` and have the logic of `if(Model <2019)` in `carGet` method

Comment: Very unclear why you expect output from constructor to show up after the method call.  And why you expect value to change when you are not changing it

Comment: Weird side effects, like console writing, in a property method? No, just no. Properties should behave as much like fields as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "old" printed as the first string is actually the `Console.WriteLine` call in the Setter. This is being called when the Constructor is being invoked.

```
public Car(string Brand, string Color, int aModel)
{
    brand = Brand;
    color = Color;
    Model = aModel; // Here - You are assigning to the Property. 
                    // Setter would now print the value due Console.WriteLine Call
}
```

You could remove the Console.WriteLine call in setter and instead you could modify your carGet as

```
Console.WriteLine(brand);
Console.WriteLine(color);
Console.WriteLine(Model < 2019 ? "Old":Model.ToString());
```

Alternatively, You could change your `Model` Property as the following,

```
 public string Model => model < 2019 ? "Old":model.ToString();
```

The above readonly property would read the value of field `model` and return a string representing the "old" or year.